# Stringbuilder (Scala) - Substituting all instances of one character with another

Tags: scala, stringbuilder

I'm trying to write a function that takes a region (from the marker pos and cursor pos) and substitutes all instances of character 'X' with character 'Y'.

For example, the user input would be the following:

```
subChar('g', 'x')
```

I know how to get the region (I think), it's just the substitution that has confused me. I've looked at similar questions on here, yet I still can't seem to get my head around it.

Also, can I simply apply the function to the region, or do I need to take the region and do something like toString() and THEN apply the rest of the syntax?

Here is what I have so far:

```
def subChar(s: Char, t: Char) {
  var region = (lwr until upr)
  region.filterNot('x' == 'y')
}
```

If anyone has any pointers I'd thoroughly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, to test it, I need lwr and upr and a String to operate on.

```
scala> def subChar (input: String, s: Char, t: Char, lwr: Int, upr: Int): String = 
     |   input.zipWithIndex.map { case (c, i) => if (i >= lwr && i < upr && c == s) t else c}.mkString ("")
subChar: (input: String, s: Char, t: Char, lwr: Int, upr: Int)String

scala> subChar ("dodadodado", 'd', 'l', 1, 5) 
res39: String = dolalodado
```

If that data is given in the outer context - as instance variables or something, you don't need them as parameters.

But notice, that a method, which returns a result, needs a '='.

Another, constant topic is, from where to count indexes and what part of interval is inclusive/exclusive so test it out and adjust it to your needs.